# Is there a `if statement`, that allows only specific type of numbers to be shown?

Tags: javascript, math

I couldn't find on w3schools.com a comparison operator, which checks if the generated number is equal to a certain type of numbers.

Is there even a method to formulate an `if statement`, without changing the `innerHTML` property of the Reference.

For example in the following oversimplified version of my code:
it should only show numbers like 6 , 3.1 , 4.05 , 53.65
(These numbers have 2, 1, or no numbers after the decimalpoint and are counted in 0.05 steps)

```js
function F1() {
  x = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = Math.random() * 100;

  if (x !== "0.05") {
    F1();
  }
  if (x !== "0.1") {
    F1();
  }
  if (x !== "1") {
    F1();
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>
<p id="x"></p>
```

Comment: (offtopic) If you don't use lnline `style=""` (as hopefully you don't) - than please stop using inline `on*=""` handlers. It' shard do debug. JS should be in one place only, and that's your `script` file or tag. And stop using w3schools as your learning resource. Still at this date (2020) they're full of crappy examples, and irrelevant code samples and certificates.

Comment: It would be much simpler to just generate the correct type of number directly instead of checking completely random numbers over and over (and it could take a *long* time to land on the kind you want.) `x = (0.05 * Math.round(Math.random() * 100 / 0.05)).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could multiply the number by 20 and round it:

```
if (Math.round(x * 20) !== x * 20) {
    // not counted in 0.05 steps, eg. 1.234
} else {
    // counted in 0.05 steps, eg. 1.25
}
```

This if statement checks if *"these numbers have 2, 1, or no numbers after the decimalpoint and are counted in 0.05 steps"* because numbers counted in 0.05 steps multiplied with 20 are integers (`Math.round(x * 20) !== x * 20` is false), eg:

```
0.05 * 20 = 1
1.25 * 20 = 25
```

and other numbers are not integers (`Math.round(x * 20) !== x * 20` is true), eg:

```
0.04 * 20 = 0.8
1.251 * 20 = 25.2
```

But using this if statement with `Math.random` is a bad idea because chances are high that `Math.random` generates so many *other* numbers that the recursion will cause a stack overflow.

A better approach is to generate the numbers you want with

```
x = Math.round(Math.random() * 20 * 100) / 20
```

Comment: Why did you multiple it by 20? I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

## Use modulus operator

However, dividing by a fraction (.05) might yield imperfect results, so it is better to multiply by 20 and check is there is a fraction reminder (modulus 1).

@Thomas Sablik's answer is valid too, and explains multiplying by 20.

```js
const isPoint05 = x => x * 20 % 1 === 0;

const test = (...args) => args.forEach(x => console.log(x, isPoint05(x)));

test(6, 3.1, 4.05, 53.65, 3.254, 6.22, 7.77, 7.33);
```

And to illustrate the challenge with fractions division (depends on the JavaScript implementation, I get 0.049999999999999614 on chrome):

```js
console.log(7 % 0.05);
```